# How do I find a filter respecting the following properties?

Tags: general-topology, filters

I'm sitting in front of the following exercise:

> Prove that if we let $\mathfrak{F}$ to be a filter on a topological space $X$ and $A\subseteq X$ with $A^c\notin \mathfrak{F}$ then there is a filter $\mathfrak{G}$ on $X$ containing $A$ which is finer than $\mathfrak{F}$

First I thought that $\mathfrak{G}=A\cup \mathfrak{F}$. But this doesn't work since the property $$\forall A,B\in \mathfrak{G}\,\,\, A\cap B\in \mathfrak{G}$$ is not satisfied. But then I didn't found another way, so it's a bit confusing since I don't see why the information $A^c\notin \mathfrak{F}$ is usful.

Could someone maybe help me finding this out?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: sorry what is the filter generated by $\mathfrak{F}$ and $A$? Could you explain this a bit more please?

Comment: Hint: If $F\in\mathfrak{F}$ does not intersect $A$, then $F\subseteq A^c$, so $A^c\in\mathfrak{F}$. Therefore every member of $\mathfrak{F}$ intersects $A$.

Comment: sorry why do we know that if $F\cap A=\emptyset$ then $F\subseteq A^c$.

Comment: So I mean if $F\cap A=\emptyset$ Then we know that $F\cap A\notin \mathfrak{F}$. but why do we have that then $F\subset A^c?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we know that $B^\complement \notin \mathfrak{F}$ we know more, in fact: for **no** $A \in \mathfrak{F}$ we can have $A \subseteq B^\complement$ (or the enlargement axiom of a filter would imply that $B^\complement \in \mathfrak{F}$, which is not the case. So stated more "positively":

$$\forall A \in \mathfrak{F}: A \cap B \neq \emptyset\tag{1}$$ to witness this non-inclusion...

Now define $$\mathfrak{G} = \{A \subseteq X\mid \exists F(A) \in \mathfrak{F}: F(A) \cap B \subseteq A\}$$

and check that this is the required filter on $X$. $(1)$ ensures $\emptyset \notin \mathfrak{G}$ and the definition itself preserves the intersection and enlargement axioms. Taking $F(B)=X$ we see that $B \in \mathfrak{G}$...

Comment: ah okey I will look at it again thanks! but your "Taking $F(B)=X$..." is the beginning of the proof of the three axioms that needs to be satisfied, right? And why exaclty do you write $F(A)$?

Comment: What I don't see yet is why do we get from this "positivly" written statement to the definition of $\mathfrak{G}$, could you explain this please?

Comment: @aprozz haven't you learnt basic set theory? If $A \cap B = \emptyset$ this means exactly that $A \subseteq B^\complement$ and this never happens by assumption.

Comment: but this wasn't my question, so I don't see why this defines $\mathfrak{G}$

Comment: @aprozz For every $A \in \mathfrak{G}$ I need some witnessing element from $\mathfrak{F}$ (whose intersection with $B$ is a subset of $A$) and I call this $F(A)$ for referencing it later. It's standard logical writing. I could also have written this element $F_A$ instead of $F(A)$, it's a choice.

Comment: @aprozz I showed in $(1)$ that we can safely add $B$ to $\mathfrak{F}$ without contradicting the empty set axiom. But just adding $B$ is not enough, we have to add all intersections with existing members too, and their supersets, and this is what my definition does in one fell swoop. You could also say: $\mathfrak{F} \cup \{B\}$  has the FIP so it generates a filter which is the same $\mathfrak{G}$. That is if you've covered generating sets of filters etc.

Comment: no we don't have discussed generating sets of filters. Ah okei but our $B$ is always fixed right?

Comment: @aprozz Then just check my definition instead. Check 3 axioms for it, $B \in \mathfrak{G}$ and $\mathfrak{F} \subseteq \mathfrak{G}$.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to prove it and I will upload it so that you can have a look

Comment: I would have proven it as follows: Assuming $\emptyset \in \mathfrak{G}$ then we find $F(\emptyset)$ s.t. $$F(\emptyset)\cap B=\emptyset\Rightarrow F(\emptyset)\subseteq B^c\Rightarrow B^c\in  \mathfrak{F}$$ which is a contradiction. Now let $U,V\in  \mathfrak{G}$ then we have $$F(U)\cap B\subseteq U, \,\,F(V)\cap B\subseteq V$$ define $F(U\cap V):=F(U)\cap F(V)\in  \mathfrak{F}$ and we have $$F(U\cap V)\cap B\subseteq U\cap V$$.  And at the end take $U\in  \mathfrak{G}$ and $U\subset V$, then $$F(U)\cap B\subseteq U\subset V$$ therefore define $F(V):=F(U)$ and thus $F(V)\cap B\subseteq V$.

Comment: does this works?

Comment: @aprozz yes for the axioms it works. Nitpick: it should say $F(\emptyset) \cap B \subseteq \emptyset$ formally. Comes down to the same thing.

Comment: yes I wrote this in my notes but then changed it to equality, can't I say that then we have equality since there is no subset of the emptyset or is that mathematically not correct

Comment: @aprozz yes, but follow the definition first.

Comment: ah perfect thanks